# How to grep alternate endings for a string

Tags: regex, grep

So Suppose

(1)

I want to grep the following:

> germania
>   german
>   germanland

from this list:

> germania
>   german 
>   germanland 
>   germanistan
>   germanburg

How do I do this with grep?

(2)

I want to grep a string starting with "abcd",  and then some stuff in the middle, and then "xkcd".  Anything can go in the middle, **except**  "foobar".

How do I do this with grep?

Much appreciated!

Comment: This isn't very well defined.  And if this is two separate questions, you should ask two separate questions.  But honestly, I can't tell what you're asking in either so I'm not sure they are.

Comment: Shall `abcdofoobari-xkcd` slip through in question 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **sed** command below is just to break the string into lines:

```
echo "germania german germanland germanistan germanburg" | sed -e 's/\ /\n/g' | grep -E "german*(ia|land|)$"
```

This was tested on bash command-line.

The important part for you is: `grep -E "german(ia|land)*$"`

`-E` means Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression. The `*` sign means *find 0 or more matches* for words ending in `ia` OR `land`. The *for words ending in* concept is represented by the `$` sign at the end.

These are good resources on grep and regexes: [linuxquestions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/) and [cyberciti](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/).

Comment: Have you tested this? I'd suggest the egrep pattern should be 'german(ia|land)*$' (note the apostrophes that prevent $ substitution)

Comment: `echo "germannia germa germannland germannistan germanburg" | sed -e 's/\ /\n/g' | grep -E "german*(ia|land|)$"` - german* means n is optional, and might be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question:

```
grep -v 'abcdfoobarxkcd' | grep 'abcd.*xkcd'
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I thought I'd comment anyway.  Karlphilip's answer works, but has the side effect of splitting the line into multiple lines and echoing them separately.  I'm not sure that's what Deniz wants.

The way I read the question is that he wants grep to find the line if it contains any occurrence of the distinct words "german", "germania" or "germanland".

This solution is similar but doesn't do the split:

```
$ echo "germanialand germanistan germanburg germania" | grep -E "\<german(ia|land|)\>"
germanialand germanistan germanburg germania

$ echo "germanistan germanburg germaniaburg" | grep -E "\<german(ia|land|)\>"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

With insufficient information, for your 1st question, since what you want to get is the first 3 fields, then simply

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3}' file
```

for the 2nd question,

```
awk '/^abcd.*xkcd/ && !/foobar/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 2nd question: lngo is mostly correct except that he wants the string to **start** with "abcd" and **end** with xkcd.

I interpret the question a bit differently too in that I think he wants to exclude anything between the opening (abcd) and close (xkcd) that has a foobar in it, and not **only** a foobar.

```
grep '^abcd.*xkcd$' | grep -v foobar
```